# Does adding pages to the spellbook do anything?

Tags: team-fortress-2

For the Halloween 2013 event, TF2 added spellbook and spellbook page items. The pages can be added to the spellbook, and the book shows what pages have been added to it. However, I have not noticed any difference in using the spellbook after adding pages. So, what changes when I add pages?

Answer (score 5):

Adding pages to the fancy spell-book do not affect the game-play/use of the item.

The only difference it makes is it increases the counters on the items loadout stats.

**Source:** [tf2 wiki](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Fancy_Spellbook)

Comment: I saw that page, and it doesn't actually say that the additional pages have no effect. It just says that the counter increases when you add pages.

Answer (score 0):

The pages add a particle effect to your spell-casting hand. Different pages have different particle effects. The more pages you add to your book, the more particles that emanate from your hand.

Comment: Do you have a source for this information?

Comment: There's a lengthy thread on it, but it starts right around here: http://facepunch.com/showthread.php?t=1266816&page=776

Comment: I can't find that information in that thread.