# What are all the new Tf2 spells and what do they do?

Tags: team-fortress-2

I am wondering what all the tf2 spells from the new Halloween 2013 update do including the fancy book ones exactly do and what they are called officially.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fancy book is just a collectible action item (explained [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/138422/does-adding-pages-to-the-spellbook-do-anything)), it does not have different spells from the spellbook magazine.  A list of 2013 magic spells may be found on the tf2 wiki at [Magic Spells](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Magic_spells):

But a quick list is

- Fireball (shoots fireballs)
- Teleport (throw an energy ball and teleport to where it lands)
- SuperJump (Jump very high)
- Healing Aura (uber and overheal youself and all allies in a short radius)
- Ball O' Bats (Throw out a ball of bats that shoots enemies up into the air and causes bleed)
- Pumpkin MIRV (Throw a bomb that produces a ring of explosive pumpkins.  Shoot the pumpkins to make them explode)
- Invisibility (Become invisible)
- Summon Monoculus (summon a small monoculus to fight for your team)
- Summon Skeletons (summon skeletons to fight for your team)(
- Tesla Bolt (Fire a wave of electricity that sucks in enemies and deals damage)
- Meteor Shower (summon fireballs to the target point, does massive damage to enemies and burns)
- Minify (become small and fast)

Comment: I would add that Minify also overheals you. Allows you to psuedo-fly by being able to jump even while in mid air. It also seems to improve the damage output of some classes (soldier) while making others fire more quickly (medic).

Answer (score -1):

From the [wiki page](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Halloween_Spells),

> Halloween Spells are single use tool items that are used to give various Halloween themed effects to weapons, hats, or classes depending on the spell. They were added in the Spectral Halloween Special, and are enabled and obtainable annually during subsequent Halloween events.
>   The Spell Items during the Scream Fortress 2012 event lasted from October 26, 2012 to November 9, 2012. Any spell effects that were applied to any items, along with any unused spells, were erased from players' inventories upon launching Team Fortress 2 after the end of the event. **They were enabled and made obtainable again for Scream Fortress 2013, which lasts from October 29, 2013 to November 11, 2013.** Halloween Spells can be found inside Haunted Halloween Gifts on Ghost Fort.

So they're special effects added to weapons/hats/classes.